# VBA .ShowAllData fails when a Chart Sheet is active

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have the code below attached to a button on a userform in Excel. There are other parts of the code that perform advanced filtering and I use the code below to clear the filter before re-applying the filter, to make it run much faster. It works just fine as long as wsDataSchool is the active sheet or some other sheet is active. However, if there is a CHART sheet active before I click the button then I get an error saying ShowAllData failed. This is super weird and I can't find anything about it. Any ideas as to why this is happening or how to fix it?

```
If wsDataSchool.FilterMode = True Then
    wsDataSchool.ShowAllData
End If
```

Comment: How is `wsDataSchool` declared? It sound like you need to be including the worksheet you want the `ShowAllData` to apply to

Comment: wsDataSchool is the codename of the worksheet I a referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a test maybe then. This tests if current sheet is a chart sheet and if so then activates the target sheet by codename.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    If wsDataSchool.FilterMode Then
        Select Case ActiveSheet.Type
        Case -4167
            wsDataSchool.ShowAllData
        Case Else
            wsDataSchool.Activate
            wsDataSchool.ShowAllData
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Although ugly, if you then need to return to a Chart sheet if in a chart sheet you could as follows:

```
Public Sub test1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Dim ws As Chart
    If wsDataSchool.FilterMode Then
        Select Case ActiveSheet.Type
        Case -4167
            wsDataSchool.ShowAllData
        Case Else
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
            wsDataSchool.Activate
            wsDataSchool.ShowAllData
            ws.Activate
        End Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: That could work, thanks. However, would you consider this a bug, since the solution only avoids the error and not really explains it.

Comment: The documentation was vague on this. The example given said you should run this in the sheet where the filter is. There is no mention of chart sheets or that it can work across sheets. I will need to look further.

Comment: What is interesting is you can run that line from within the code pane of the chart sheet itself which makes you wonder about scope.

Comment: It really is weird. I guess I will leave it that way and go with how it is.

Comment: I will use `If  Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then` instead of `Select Case ActiveSheet.Type`